# на selenium webdriver js нужно вывести содержимое всех тегов с классом item

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Пишу автотест на selenium webdriver js, в котором нужно вывести содержимое тегов div class="item" (' Item 1 ', ... ' Item 4 '). Пробовал получить массив класса list  с дочерними элементами item и найти все элементы по классу item и перебрать в цикле, но у меня ничего не вышло. Подскажите как это сделать 
autotest.js:

```
const { By, Key, until } = require("selenium-webdriver");
const webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver");
require("chromedriver");
let promise = require("selenium-webdriver").promise;

await driver.get('http://www.test.site')
let pendingElements = driver.findElements(By.className('item'))

pendingElements.then(function (elements) {
let pendingHtml = elements.map(function (elem) {
    return elem.getInnerHtml();
});

promise.all(pendingHtml).then(function (allHtml) {
    console.log(allHtml); // Здесь по логике я должен получить массив значений (Item 1, Item 2 ...)
});
});
```

test.site.html:

```
<body>
  <div class="list>
    <div class="item">
      <div>
       <strong> Item 1 </strong>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div>
       <strong> Item 2 </strong>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div>
       <strong> Item 3 </strong>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div>
       <strong> Item 4 </strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Добавил код из предложенной ссылки - выдает ошибку (not a function):

```
TypeError: pendingElementsConfigList.then is not a function
at autoTest (/home/automation_testing/tests/autoTest.js:69:35)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Если вывести нулевой элемент:
console.log(pendingElements[0]);
то в консоли выведет это:

```
WebElement {
  driver_:
   Driver {
     session_: Promise { [Session] },
     executor_:
      Executor { w3c: true, customCommands_: [Map], log_: [Logger] },
     fileDetector_: null,
     onQuit_: [Function: onQuit] },
  id_: Promise { '781fdd8b-08e5-4aee-8ce6-c3b800a75956' } }
```

И из этого как-то нужно вывести значения элементов с классом item

Comment: Подобный вопрос уже задавали, посмотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35098156/get-an-array-of-elements-from-findelementby-classname)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    let findButtons = await driver.findElements(By.tagName(`strong`));

    let buttons = findButtons.map(elem => elem.getText());
    const allButtons = await Promise.all(buttons);

    //    ***   Find button  ***
    let targetButton;
    for (let i = 0; i < findButtons.length; i++) {
      if (allButtons[i] == `Item 2`) {
        targetButton = await findButtons[i];
        targetButton.click();
      }
    }
```